# How to install desktop and VNC?

Tags: 14.04, apt, dpkg, vnc

I am trying to install desktop and VNC but I keep getting errors..

So first I execute:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

but I keep getting this errors:

```
Setting up ubuntu-sso-client-qt (13.10-0ubuntu6) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) ...
Processing triggers for libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64 (2.30.7-0ubuntu1.2) ...
Processing triggers for libreoffice-common (1:4.2.8-0ubuntu4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bluez
 bluez-alsa:amd64
 gnome-bluetooth
 gnome-user-share
 indicator-bluetooth
 unity-control-center
 ubuntu-desktop
 unity-control-center-signon
 webaccounts-extension-common
```

Can you help me please? Thanks a lot. By the way, I tried a lot of tutorials, I tried the command `apt-get upgrade`, some fixes but nothing has helped me..

I use putty and I have Ubuntu 14.04-64bit(Vps).

Comment: Have you tried the apt-get update && apt-get upgrade sequence?

Comment: Try executing `sudo apt-get install -f` and if it doesn't work then ` 
sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: So I tried ´apt-get update && apt-get upgrade' then  ´sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop' and got same error.

Comment: Then I tried commands from Thanos and I am getting this errors http://m.imgur.com/CuSohl2